# Realising rotating paths for backup purposes?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I want to run an image backup (using command line on windows) once a day. I want to keep one image for each of the last three days, so I have to rotate between 3 paths on each backup run, e.g.

```
c:\image0.ext // encode as 0, see text below
c:\image1.ext // encode as 1
c:\image2.ext // encode as 2
```

I though about writing 0, 1 or 2 in a text file, reading it's value somehow, then do sth. like (number+1) mod 2, execute backup, write the new number to the text file. I would then link each number from 0 to 2 to a path using an if statement. Are there better/easier ways for that? Thanks for any hint!

Comment: Is image0.ext a file or a folder?

Comment: Let's say those 3 are strings between which I need to switch ;-) No seriously, imageX.ext means a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since imageX.ext is a file, I assume it is some compressed archive of your data analagous to a zip file. The modified date should get updated each time it is replaced with a new version, so you should not need a separate file to keep track of what is your most recent image. You can use DIR sorted by date to get the most recent image (last one listed).

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /od c:\image?.ext') do set lastImage=%%F
set /a nextImage=(%lastimage:~-5,1%+1)%%3
set nextImage="c:\image%nextImage%.ext"
```

This algorithm will break if someone creates another file that matches your file mask after your last image was taken.

Comment: Thank you, learned a lot by your code snippet! The images will have their own directory, so no problem. But why are you using %%3? Using just one percentage sign %3 also seems to work the same way?

Comment: my fault, %3 is not really doing modulo ;-)

Comment: oh, i am getting missing bracket on line 2 (the one setting nextImage)?

Comment: sorry, my fault, please ignore. Skript needs exisiting file or it runs in trouble. no problem for me though.